Issues with Using v-slot to Insert HTML Code into SVG Elements in Vue
Issues with Using v-slot to Insert HTML Code into SVG Elements in Vue
Description:
I'm using v-slot to insert HTML code (from the parent) into an SVG element of a child component via JavaScript.
I want to place some elements in the SVG (e.g., input box, image...), but it depends on what the parent provides to the child component.
The reason why I must use this function is that I want to generate a Number line and replace some Numbers to html element.
However, when I run the code, I find that the slot element is empty. It seems that the slot does not inherit the parent's HTML. But if I place the  outside the SVG, it works. Am I making a mistake in using v-slot?
Full Code Here:
Parent
Child
Here is part of my code:
Parent Component:
<template>
  <div>
    <NumberLine>
      <template v-slot>
        <input type="text">
      </template>
    </NumberLine>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import NumberLine from './NumberLine.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        NumberLine
    },
    name: 'TestParentNode'
};
</script>


Child Component:
<template>
  <div class="OutterContainer">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg"></svg>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'NumberLine',
  mounted() {
    let Svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    Svg.appendChild(this.SvgAddComponent(10, 20));
    
  },
  methods: {
        SvgAddComponent(x, y) {
          let component = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
          component.setAttribute('x', x);
          component.setAttribute('y', y);
          component.setAttribute('width', 30);
          component.setAttribute('height', 30);
          let slot = document.createElement('slot');
          component.appendChild(slot);
          return component;
        }
  }
}
</script>

Dev Tools Information:

Thanks for your patience

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem, it's unclear how these snippets are related. If you want to use vue slots inside svg, stick to using vue templates or render functions and avoid accessing dom directly

@RobertLongson Thank you for your response. I understand that there is no  element in the SVG specification. Typically, when we use the  tag in a child component, Vue will pass the HTML from the parent to the child. I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve the same functionality within an SVG element, or if I need to use a different approach to embed HTML elements provided by the parent inside an SVG in a Vue component.

@EstusFlask Sorry for the confusion caused by my initial question. I have updated my code. Please take another look. Thank you for your guidance.

@3limin4t0r you can put HTML elements as children of foreignObject, that's why the foreignObject tag exists. If you want to create a HTML element, you must use the HTML namespace though. That's what the OP's original problem was but the question has changed since it was originally asked.

@Rduan I see. Is there a reason why you didn't do what SvgAddComponent does in component template? Because this is how it's generally supposed to be done. return component - you don't use it anywhere any way, can you clarify what was your intention?

@RobertLongson Thank you for your reply. I understand I made some mistakes in the first version, so I have updated the question.

@EstusFlask Thanks for your reply. I think that is another mistake. I've updated my code and provided the full code as well. Please take another look. The reason why I didn't do what SvgAddComponent does in the component template is that sometimes I need it and sometimes I don't. The details on how I handle it are in my full code.

You're supposed to handle this logic with v-if and v-for, it's doable. You can write this in more flexible way with render function instead of template, but here I don't see anything that would require this. The recommendation stays the same, avoid accessing dom directly in vue.

Got it, I'll find another way to solve this question. Thanks for your reply.

Here is it should be look like:
Parent Component:
<template>
  <div>
    <NumberLine>
        <input type="text">
    </NumberLine>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import NumberLine from './NumberLine.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        NumberLine
    },
    name: 'ParentNode'
};
</script> 

Child Component:
<template>
  <div class="OutterContainer">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg">
    </svg>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
      name: 'NumberLine',
      mounted() {
        let Svg = document.querySelector('svg');
        Svg.appendChild(this.SvgAddComponent(10, 20, 30, 30));
        
      },
      methods: {
            SvgAddComponent(x, y, width, height) {
              let component = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
              component.setAttribute('x', x);
              component.setAttribute('y', y);
              component.setAttribute('width', width);
              component.setAttribute('height', height);
              let slot = document.createElement('slot');
              component.appendChild(slot);
              return component;
            }
      }
    }
 </script>

this should be work

Thanks for your reply. But that code still not working, Result.
